# What's this linux structure

Tags: linux

```
#define GPIO_CHIP(_bank) { \
    .irq_base = IRQ_GPIO_BASE_ ## _bank, \
    .gpio_chip = { \
        .label = "Bank " # _bank, \
        .owner = THIS_MODULE, \
        .set = gpio_set_value, \
        .get = gpio_get_value, \
        .direction_output =gpio_direction_output, \
        .direction_input = gpio_direction_input, \
        .base = GPIO_BASE_ ## _bank, \
        .ngpio =GPIO_NUM_ ## _bank, \
    }, \
}
```

What's this define with .label and .set and others?

```
static void gpio_set_value(struct gpio_chip *chip, unsigned gpio, int value)
{
    uint32_t __iomem *reg = CHIP_TO_REG(chip, REG_GPIO_DATA_SET);
    reg += !value;
    writel(BIT(gpio), reg);
}
```

This function with writel, __iomen, BIT() , where are they referenced from in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

`GPIO_CHIP` is used to initialize a struct for a bank of GPIO (General Purpose I/O). If you have

```
struct s {
   int a, b, c;
   char * d;
}
```

then you can initialize a variable like

```
struct s example = { .a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 3, .d = "Hello!" };
```

You could also do it like

```
struct s example = { 1, 2, 3, "Hello!" };
```

but in that case you need to keep track of the order of the members of the struct, it isn't obvious at a glance what `1`, `2`, etc. actually being used for, and it can get out of sync easily.

If you need to initialize a lot of variables like this you can use a `#define` which is just the initializer, like

```
#define S_INIT(num) { .a = num, .b = 2, .c = 3 }
struct s example = S_INIT(0);
struct s examples[] = { S_INIT(1), S_INIT(2), S_INIT(3) };
```

`GPIO_CHIP` sets the function pointer `.gpio_chip.set` in the structure to point to `gpio_set_value`, so any call to that function is likely through that function pointer.

Consult the [kernel documentation for the GPIO driver interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/driver.txt) for details.